# BUILD ERROR The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Tags: maven

```
Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'eclipse'.
 org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
NG] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
 Repository 'central' will be blacklisted

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
] BUILD ERROR
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total time: 22 seconds
 Finished at: Fri Aug 26 17:42:01 IST 2011
 Final Memory: 3M/15M
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely due to a possibly temporary network problem. While we're at it, if you plan to use Maven together with Eclipse do not use `maven-eclipse-plugin` but rather the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)/[m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/new-and-noteworthy.html) Eclipse plugin. Which one depends on which version of Eclipse you are using; m2e is the one that's actively developed, but only works with 3.7 (Indigo), m2eclipse is the legacy version that works with 3.6 (Helios).

Comment: Thanks Nicola, But I am using Spring Source Tool Suite,Where currently source code is not available. Will the given solution will be fine for STS Please let me know.

Comment: I never used Spring STS but I would expect it to already include the either m2e or m2eclipse. To make sure select Help -> Install new software... and click on the What's already installed link. See if the list contains something related to Maven, e.g. "Maven integration for Eclipse". If it does you can import maven projects directly into STS by choosing Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for this:

- a network problem as Nicola mentioned earlier

If the plugin actually exists in the Maven repository, then

- the repository could have been created with a different version of Maven
- sometime the repository files get corrupted and a solution could be to run maven with `-U` switch
- if previous solution doesn't work, try deleting the entire repository and let Maven re-download all the files